# Laravel secure Amazon s3 bucket files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3, laravel-4

I am using Amazon s3 but here i am facing two problems

1.I can't directly upload files to amazon server when i submit form.I mean i have to upload images to an `upload folder` on my PHP server and from there i have to retrieve and upload them to `s3 server`. Is there a way to upload images directly to `s3` when we click on submit?

2.If i pass `'public'` in `s3 put object` then i can access or view files, but if i make it public every one can view files. But i need to protect all files and view only to the authenticated user. Can any one suggest me how to fix this issue?

```
try {           
    $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
    $s3->put($strFileName, file_get_contents($img_path.$strFileName), 'public');
} catch (Aws\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n"+$e;
}
```

Before asking questions i have read many answers from stackoverflow but it didnt helped me to fix my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently tackled this problem. First off yes you can upload directly to s3 here is what I used for some info on this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html

First off you need to create a policy and signature server side to add to your html form for uploading files.

```
$policy = base64_encode(json_encode([
            "expiration" => "2100-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "conditions" => [
                ["bucket"=> "bucketname"],
                ["starts-with", '$key', "foldername"],
                ["acl" => "public-read"],
                ["starts-with", '$Content-Type', "image/"],
                ["success_action_status" => '201'],
            ]
        ]));
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',$policy,getenv('S3_SECRET_KEY'),true));
```

Now on the frontend my form I don't use a submit button, you could use a submit button but you will need to catch the submit and prevent the form from actually submitting till after the upload finishes.

When we click save, it generates an md5 (use npm to install) filename so that file names can't really be guessed randomly, it then uses ajax to upload the file up to S3. After this is finished it puts the file data and returned aws data in a hidden input and submits the form. It should look something like this:

```
<form action="/post/url" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="other_field" />
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image_uploader" name="file" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_medias" name="medias" value="[]" />
</form>
<input type="button" value="save" id="save" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
            uploadImage(function () {
                $('#form').submit();
            });
    });
});
var uploadImage = function(callback) {
    var file = $('#image_uploader')[0].files[0];
    if(file !== undefined) {
        var data = new FormData();
        var filename = md5(file.name + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
        var filenamePieces = file.name.split('.');
        var extension = filenamePieces[filenamePieces.length - 1];
        data.append('acl',"public-read");
        data.append('policy',"{!! $policy !!}");
        data.append('signature',"{!! $signature !!}");
        data.append('Content-type',"image/");
        data.append('success_action_status',"201");
        data.append('AWSAccessKeyId',"{!! getenv('S3_KEY_ID') !!}");
        data.append('key',filename + '.' + extension);
        data.append('file', file);

        var fileData = {
            type: file.type,
            name: file.name,
            size: file.size
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

            success: function (awsData) {
                var xmlData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(awsData);
                var currentImages = JSON.parse($('#hidden_medias').val());
                currentImages.push({
                    awsData: xmlData,
                    fileData: fileData
                });
                $('#hidden_medias').val(JSON.stringify(currentImages));
                callback();
            },
            error: function (errorData) {
                console.log(errorData);
            }
        });
    }
};
</script>
```

The controller listening for the submit then parses the JSON from that input field and creates an instance of Media (a model I created) and it stores the `awsData` and `fileData` for each image.

Then instead of pointing html image tags to the s3 file like this:

```
<img src="https://{bucketname}.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.jpg" />
```

I do something like this:

```
<img src="/medias/{id}" />
```

Then the route can go through the normal `auth` middleware and all you need to do in Laravel. Finally, that route points to a controller that does this:

```
public function getResponse($id)
{
    $media = Media::find($id);
    return (new Response('',301,['Location' => $media->info['aws']['Location']]));
}
```

So what this does is simply uses a 301 redirect and sets the header location to the actual aws file. Since we generate an md5 filename when we upload the file to aws each filename is an md5 so people couldn't randomly search for aws files in the bucket.

Comment: @Pitchinnate.Thanks for the more detail.surely i will try and let you know .Thanks a lot for taking time to explain

Comment: @Pitchinnate..for me now important is to protect images from unauthorized person.you have explained it clear still i got confused how to use it i.if you dont mind is it possible to explain it little further on retrieving images from s3 securely

Comment: So technically someone the images are not fully protected but it makes it hard one someone trying to get them. The request for the image comes to Laravel first and Laravel is able to verify that the user is logged in and has permission to view the image (can be done with middleware). If the user does have permission it sends back a 301 to and location to the actual file.

Comment: The file on s3 is technically public but since it is an md5 file name people can't just guess file names. The only way they would ever even see the the md5 file name and route to AWS would be to be an authorized user, view the image, open up the Network Tab in debug tools of the browser and look at the response headers.

Comment: Also I have a blog post about this that goes into a little more detail: http://natedenlinger.com/uploading-files-directly-to-aws-s3-in-laravel-5-3/

Comment: @Pitchinnate.Thank you so much.will try once

Comment: Why exposing to the whole world the environment variable `S3_KEY_ID`?

Comment: it isn't exposing it, gets hashed before it is sent to the client side.

Answer (score 5):

For you first question, it can be directly upload images to AWS S3.

```
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver();
$s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file), array('ContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $file_name . '', 'ACL' => 'public-read'));
```

You are supposed to specify your file path and the file you get from the form.

Comment: thanks for the answer do you know how to access private images or to protect images from public

Answer (score 3):

**1. is there a way to upload images directly when we click on submit**

Yes

How:

You need to do this using JavaScript (with AJAX) in two parts;

a) when user clicks "submit" you trap this event, first upload the file (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html for an example), and
 b) then submit the form through AJAX and handle the response.

However:

This allows the user to upload anything and may cause problems. There are tips (just below the example) to create authenticated URLs for 15 minutes (variable) but what happens if a user takes longer than 15 minutes, or tries to upload 100 files in 15 minutes, or uploads something other than an images file, or a badly formatted image file etc.

It's much safer to pull into your server and verify they are images and of the type/size you need and then upload from the server.

Of course, if this is a simple admin tool and you are controlling who accesses the code then go for it - hopefully you'll only upload what you expect.

**2. i need to protect all files and view only to the authenticated user**

By "authenticated user": if you mean "the user that uploaded the image" then s3 alone does not provide the functionality, but CloudFront does. You can issue pre-authorised URLs or signed cookies: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html

If "authenticated user" means the person that uploaded the file, then according to the docs, this is not possible in Laravel class without getting access to the underlying client. `public` and `private` are your only visibility options by default, which are translated to `public-read`, but you need `authenticated-read`, `bucket-owner-read` or one of the other canned grants (ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) If the `authenticated-read` or other canned ACL grants don't give the permissions profile you need, you can create your own (details further up on that same page).

Solution is to grab the underlying client and then do put-object directly. (And then if you go that far, you may as well ditch the Laravel library and pull in s3 and do it all yourself - then you have full control of everything).

```
$client = $disk->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient();

$client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $fileName,
    'Body'   => $fileBody,
    'ACL'    => 'authenticated-read'  /* Or which ACL suits */
]);
```

Comment: @Robbie.Thanks for the detailed answer.'ACL'    => 'authenticated-read' okay.how i can retrieve it .because i am new be to amazon s3 server.thanks again

Comment: What bit do you need a coding example for? The best reference for doing stuff outside the laravel library is the AWS SDK for PHP (here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject)

Answer (score 2):

Solution to your question which I'm also using but without laravel.

**1. For uploading any file directly to Amazon AWS S3 Bucket in specific folder you can do it like this.**

**HTML**

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <button type="submit">Upload file</button>
</form>
```

**PHP - upload.php**

**Include aws php sdk**

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
```

**Initialize S3 Client**

```
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials(
    '<AWS ACCESS KEY>', 
    '<AWS ACCESS SECRET>'
);

$s3Client = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(
    [
        'credentials' => credentials
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ]
);
```

**Create file upload entity**

```
$uploadEntity = array(
    'Bucket' => <S3 Bucket Name>,
    'Key'    => '<Upload_Folder_If_Any>/<FileName>',
    'Body'   => fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r+'),
    //'ContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="<FileName>"' <-- If need to allow downloading
);
```

**Upload to s3 Bucket**

```
try {
    // $result will be Aws\Result object
    $result = $s3Client->putObject($uploadEntity);  
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $exception) {
    // S3 Exception
}
```

**2. Now for serve the uploaded files to authenticated users only**

Firstly, you will need to create private bucket policy for the s3 Bucket.

**Bucket Policy** - To generate the bucket policy you can use [Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html). Using this you can generate policy like this. Copied from [Improve.dk website](http://improve.dk/how-to-set-up-and-serve-private-content-using-s3/)

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1319566876317",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1319566860498",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BucketName>/*",
      "Principal": {
        "CanonicalUser": [
          "<CannoicalUserId_of_OAI>"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Secondly, you will need to setup the private web distribution of cloudfront the s3 Bucket. Only doing that you will be able to serve your contents to authenticated users only through **aws signed url or signed cookie**

Thirdly, to generate the signed url, you will need the **pem** file which you will get from aws console only.

**Generate signed url**

```
$cdnName = '<AWS CLOUDFRONT WEB DISTRIBUTION CDN>';
$assetName = '<UPLOAD_FOLDER_IF_ANY>/<FILENAME>';
$expiry = time() + 300;     // 5 mins expiry time, ie. the signed url will be valid only for 5 mins

$cloudfront = CloudFrontClient::factory(array(
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest'
));

// Use this for creating signed url
$signedUrl = $cloudFront->getSignedUrl([
    'url'         => $cdnName . '/' . $assetName,
    'expires'     => $expiry,
    'private_key' => '/path/to/your/cloudfront-private-key.pem',
    'key_pair_id' => '<cloudfront key pair id>'
]);

// Use this for signed cookie    
$signedCookie = $cloudFront->getSignedCookie([
    'url'         => $cdnName . '/' . $assetName,
    'expires'     => $expiry,
    'private_key' => '/path/to/your/cloudfront-private-key.pem',
    'key_pair_id' => '<cloudfront key pair id>'
]);
```

Comment: @Haridarshan.Thanks for the answerwill try later

Comment: @iCoders Will add some more basic things required for setting up s3 bucket policy and private web distribution.